# A Question on Religion

Tags: knowledge

So... you go to church everyday. And you can memorize the Bible front to back. And I can give you a page number and you can instantly recite the entire verse from memory?

Then, good sir, I will give you an easy question.

> How many of each species did Moses take on the ark with him?

Comment: are you absolutely certain that this is a **riddle**?

Comment: @ABcDexter Took off the riddle tag :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LOL

> None...Moses didn't have an ark...

And by the way, this is not a riddle.

Comment: Technically, [he did have one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ark_of_the_Covenant), just not *that* one.

Comment: @Apep Ahh good job. Will you mind if I incorporate that into my answer?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: Noice +1 my answer kind of compliments yours btw.